# Javascript: Object with methods vs. function with a switch

Tags: javascript

I'm still relatively new to JS and am trying to determine if there's a benefit to one of these two options over the other.

I work frequently with arrays and wanted to have a multitool available to do whatever I'd like with them at a given time.

Here are my two options I'm trying to decide between:

```
  const arr = {
    arrCreate: function(v){
      if (!Array.isArray(v)) {
        v = [v];
      };
      return v;
    },

    arrString: function(v){
      v = v.length === 1 ? v.toString() : v;
      return v;
    },

    arrShift: function(v){
      if (v.length > 1) {
        v.shift();
      };
      return v;
    };
  };

  var array = arr.arrString(array);
```

Vs.

```
    function arr(v,v2){
        switch(v2){
          case 'array':
            if (!Array.isArray(v)) {
              v = [v]
            };
            break;

          case 'string':
            v = v.length === 1 ? v.toString() : v;
            break;

          case 'shift':
            if (v.length > 1){
              v.shift()
            };
            break;

            default:
        }
      return v;
    }
    var array = arr(array,"string");
```

These two are functionally identical (AFAIK), but I'm guessing one of them has a performance benefit over the other which I'm unaware of. Which would be preferred and why?

Comment: The first call would be `arr.arrString(array)`... also it seems weird that you're declaring `var array` in the same statement that you're using it as a function parameter.

Comment: OK, *forget about performance*. The difference, if any, is going to be negligible. Think about which is easier to maintain because *that* is what most of your time is going to be spent on.

Comment: To piggy-back @VLAZ maintenance is more important that productivity in the vast majority of cases.  In light of which, I would say avoid the switch version as it is hardly used, whereas the other version is the well-known "module" pattern that we are all familiar with.

Comment: Perhaps unrelated, but imo all three of these helper functions are implemented better in native javascript: `Array.of()`, `arr = arr.toString()`, `arr.shift()` have more predictable and useful behavior than the three alternatives here

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Good catch, thanks!

Comment: @Klaycon In this case, I need to evaluate the argument prior to returning the value. For example, I may pass an array with a length of 1 or more, and I don't want to .shift() the array unless it has a length of 2+.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `switch` is

- harder to read (intentionally violates the [single responsibility principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) by executing many unrelated tasks based on a parameter)
- harder to write (just try to forget a `break`)
- slightly harder to test (ensuring its full coverage)
- a bit clumsier to call (`thing.do(thing,args)` instead of `thing.dothing(args)`).

If you are doing it solely because of the `return v;`, you could use arrow functions, like

```
v => Array.isArray(v) ? v : [v]
v => v.length === 1 ? v.toString() : v
```

(the 3rd one needs the return)

Comment: …and much easier to mess up, by misspelling the enum string. A method call with the wrong name will give a meaningful error message, or even can be detected with static analysis.

Comment: @Bergi yes, that too. Though `default` can throw something if it really wants to, in runtime, of course.

Comment: What was nagging at the back of my mind was the fact that I was passing two arguments into the function containing the switch as opposed to solely handing off and then returning the value with the object methods. Excellent points and thanks for taking the time to answer. :)

Answer (score -1):

I would say that the performance difference wouldn't be noticeable however the first option would be the preferred method because you are specifying which of the functions you want to use. For example if you wanted to convert your array to a string you would use `arr.arrString(array)` and that would be the end of it. Additional code inside of your `arr` object wouldn't need to be run as it would in the second option. The second option would have to go through the switch statement until it found the particular case that you were looking for.

In addition, using `arr.arrString(array)` would be more meaningful to other users that are going through your code as opposed to `arr(array, 'string')`. It also eliminates the need for normalizing the string that is being passed...say someone used `arr(array, 'String')` that would cause an error because `'String'` isn't defined as a case.

Comment: If you're going to downvote you could at least say why in a comment...

Comment: Yeah, not sure why about the downvotes because you raise a great point with the normalizing of "string" vs. "String" that I hadn't considered.

Comment: "*I would say that the first is slightly more performant*" I would say that the performance impact is going to be negligible at best and most likely immeasurable. In any case, it's going to be of no actual consequence to the running of the entire application, as any performance bottleneck would be elsewhere. If your code triggers the browser reflow three times instead of one, that is probably going to have a bigger hit to the running time and yet it's still imperceptible and not worth optimising. So, don't focus on performance here.